# How to find a single value in a nested list (and its position) with minimal iterations?

Tags: python, nested, iteration

Say I have the following nested list:

```
my_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['a', 'c'],
]
```

I want to find any values that appear only once in the entire list, and also their position in the parent list. For example, `'e'` appears only once, and it's in `my_list[2]`.

The only ways I can think of doing this involve at least three iterations. For example:

```
for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:  # Iteration 1
    count = 0
    for child_list in my_list:            # Iteration 2
        if letter in child_list:
            count += 1
    if count == 1:
        print(letter)
        for i in range(len(my_list)):     # Iteration 3
            if letter in my_list[i]:
                print(i)
```

or:

```
counter = {}
for i in range(len(my_list)):         # Iteration 1
    for letter in my_list[i]:         # Iteration 2
        if letter not in counter:
            # Store the count and (first) position of each letter
            counter[letter] = [1, i]
        else:
            counter[letter][0] += 1
for letter in counter:                # Iteration 3
    if counter[letter][0] == 1:
        print(letter)
        print(counter[letter][1])
```

Is there a way of doing this that doesn't require so many iterations?

Comment: Not all of your iterations are the same. In your first two loops your are iterating over every item and in the third only over every distinct value. Also technically during your first two loops you are iterating only once. That being said I think your solution is already optimal.

Comment: I was about to comment on that, what matters is the number of times that each item is tested, no?

Comment: what would be the exact expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do what your question asks using a python set and dict:

```py
my_list = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['a', 'c'],
]

visited = set()
singletons = {}
for i, L in enumerate(my_list):
    for v in L:
        if v not in visited:
            visited.add(v)
            singletons[v] = i
        else:
            singletons.pop(v, None)
print(singletons)
```

Output:

```
{'e': 2}
```

Comment: @BWPanda Do you need any more help with your question? If this answer (or one of the others) has addressed your question, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way with a single iteration (i.e. each element is visited only once) that creates a dictionary of {letter: [count, first position]}:

```
d = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(my_list):
    for item in lst:
        if item in d:
            d[item][0] +=1
        else:
            d[item] = [1, i]
```

output:

```
{'a': [3, 0], 'b': [2, 0], 'c': [4, 0], 'd': [3, 0], 'e': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: Isn't that two iterations? And I think you would need one more to get the answer i.e. filtering for single occurrence

Comment: @not_speshal not in the sense that each item is seen only once

Comment: @mozway, looks like we arrived at very similar solutions, plus or minus a pop().

Comment: @constantstranger actually twice I wanted to update my solution but i was like you changed (add/discard, then pop), so I'll leave it to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, not sure if this is what you are after but here it is:

```
x = 0
y = 0
output = {}
duplicates = []
while x < len(my_list):
    if y < len(my_list[x]):
        value = my_list[x][y]
        y = y + 1
        if value in output:
            del output[value]
            duplicates.append(value)
        elif not value in output and not value in duplicates:
            output[value] = x
    else:
        y = 0
        x = x + 1
```

What you get is:

```
{'e': 2}
```

It is a single loop but work involved is probably comparable to running two nested loops.